# Date does not match format in python datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, strptime, python-datetime

Why do I have an error in Python `datetime.strptime` if `MINYEAR` may be 1? My setup is Mac OSX 10.10.2 Python 3.4.

```
from datetime import *
    def days_diff(date1, date2):
        c=datetime.strptime('.'.join(str(i) for i in date1),"%Y.%m.%d")
        d=datetime.strptime('.'.join(str(i) for i in date2),"%Y.%m.%d")
        return print(c,d)

    days_diff((1, 1, 1), (9999,12,31))

ValueError: time data '1.1.1' does not match format '%Y.%m.%d'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%Y` format only works for years using *four digits*:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('0001.1.1', '%Y.%m.%d')
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

You could use `str.zfill()` to pad out your 'date' string:

```
c = datetime.strptime('.'.join(str(i) for i in date1).zfill(8), "%Y.%m.%d")
d = datetime.strptime('.'.join(str(i) for i in date2).zfill(8), "%Y.%m.%d")
```